# Start bot with one message and end with other command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, setinterval

I'm basically creating a bot that does a loop, and I want it to end when you say `*parar` but i don't know how to make it.

Here is a bit of code to explain my problem

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'epico',
    execute(message, args, Discord, client){

    //this is the loop
    var interval = setInterval(function(){...}, 1000)

}
```

The loop starts when I put `*epico` and I want it to stop when user sends `*parar`

I was trying something like this:

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(message.content.startsWith('parar')){clearInterval(interval)}
}
```

But this keeps working until I shut down the bot (I want it to just work 1 time)

Comment: You're missing a `)` in your if-statement

Comment: Is the code in the same file, or in separate ones? I assume the command is in another file, if so, you need to pass `interval` function to your main code. Either that or maybe show us more of your code? (Especially the interaction between both files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following: Basically what you want to do is save your interval to a variable that is accessible later on in order to stop your interval again.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

let interval;

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("*epico")) {
    return (interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("do something");
    }, 1000));
  }

  if (message.content.startsWith("*parar")) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    return console.log("stopped interval");
  }
});

client.login("your-token");
```

I assume your are using multiple commands in several different files. If that is the case I would simply save the interval to the client object in your `*epico` command file since you pass the `client` to your `execute` function anyways.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "epico",
  execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    return (client.interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("do something");
    }, 1000));
  },
};
```

And then just clear the interval in your `*parar` command. Also don't forget to check if `client.interval` is even set ;)

```
module.exports = {
  name: "parar",
  execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    client.interval && clearInterval(client.interval);
    return console.log("stopped interval");
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have a typo???

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('parar')){
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
});
```

Comment: nono, the code work fine, but it just keep working like, if instead clearInterval it was message.channel.send and i say 'parar' it will send the message, but no mather what if i say 'para' another time it will till sending de message. Am i clear? i dont speak english so sorry if you dont understand me :(